# CloudFormation: Create a resource only in specific stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a use case where I want to create a resource only in test environment using cloud formation. I'm trying to use conditionals to achieve this but it fails.

```
 Resources: 
    TestClientRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Condition: NotProdStage
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Action: <>
              Effect: Allow
              <>
            Version: '2012-10-17'
          RoleName:
            "some-test-role"
```

It works fine in non-prod stages, but fails with "Unresolved resource dependencies [TestClientRole] in the Resources block of the template"

How to make cloud formation ignore resources for prod stages?

Comment: Are you saying it works fine for non-prod, but displays that particular error when it is in **prod** stage? That is, when `NotProdStage` is false?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein correct

Comment: I also see some issues with the template in the resource `TestClientRole` block. Are you sure this resource is getting created correctly? For ex: The `Principal` tag is missing in `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`. The values passed to `Action` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is indicating that there is a dependency on `TestClientRole` elsewhere in your CloudFormation template.

The problem is that the Role is *not* being created in a Prod environment, yet the other resource is saying that it is dependent on the role being created.

**Solution:** Remove the dependency elsewhere in your template that refers to `TestClientRole`.

In fact, it is very rare to actually *require* dependencies because CloudFormation figures out the correct build order based upon references between resources. The only time you need a dependency is when you specifically want one thing to finish building before another starts, such as having an app server wait until a database server is ready. Typically, leave them out unless you have a particular need that is non-obvious.